# Google Analytics is sayng:No hits! Either your site is not receiving any sessions or it is not tagged correctly

Tags: google-analytics

According to google analytic my site is not receiving hits. I have added the google analytic code in the head section of the site, in all the pages.

When I checked the site using Google Tag Assistant, it gave an error that "No HTTP response detected".  What does this mean? Is this the reason why my site is not receiving hits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"No HTTP response detected" means that no information is sent to the Google Analytics tracking servers (actually rather that it does not arrive there), so yes, that is the reason why you do not see any interactions in Google Analytics.

One possible reason is that you have an adblocker ([this would be part of the complete error message](https://support.google.com/tagassistant/answer/3059154?hl=en#http_response)).

If I recall correctly the same error will show up in the Tag Assistant if you have entered a wrong value for the cookie domain, so you might want to check that is set correctly when you create the tracker (setting it to auto is usually the easiest way):

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
```

Have a look at your browsers developement tools, the browser console will probably have additional error messages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply......I copied the GA code again and checked Tag Assistant and after the change no error is showing up, it says the tag is working fine and no errors in browser console.

Any ideas how can I verify this is the problem and it is no resolved?

Comment: Can you share an Url (maybe via a link shortener) ?

Answer (score 0):

No Hits

First detected: Mar 27, 2022 10:59:58 PM
Last detected: Jun 15, 2022 10:46:48 AM

Property 5thquartersportscards.net is not receiving hits. Either your site is not receiving any sessions or it is not tagged correctly.

Google Tag Assistant Recordings can help you ensure that your site is tagged correctly.

Learn more: https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=1008080&hl=en-US